# What is the difference between assigning to exports vs. module?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module

Consider the following code, based on the "loose augmentation" module pattern described at http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

```
var FOO = (function(exports) {

  //What is the difference between this:
  exports.hello = "hello";
  return exports;

}(FOO || {}));

var FOO = (function(exports) {

  //And this:
  FOO.world = "world";
  return exports;

}(FOO || {}));

//When the result works either way:
alert(FOO.hello + " " + FOO.world);
```

In this example, why would one assign to `exports` vs. `FOO` when it works the same either way? What is the difference?

Comment: There isn't. The bonus to using something like `exports` is that you automatically tell the reader what you're exporting. You can figure out that `FOO.world` is the same as `exports.world` or you can just be explicit and write `exports.world`. Then all of your code follows the same kind of pattern. It gives the reader one less thing to think about.

Answer (score 2):

The two versions are not equivalent. The second one gives an error when you try to assign `FOO.world` because at that point FOO is still undefined. Right now your code is only working because the first module definition is creating the FOO object.

As for why have the `exports` variable the main reason is that it decouples the module definition from the module name. You only need to write the module name (FOO) once and if you are in a serverside environment, you might not even need to use the module name (its implied from the file name).

Notice how in the link you game, even the simple "Module Export" version already uses a "my" variable for the module instead of assigning to MODULE directly:

```
var MODULE = (function () {
    var my = {},
        privateVariable = 1;

    function privateMethod() {
        // ...
    }

    my.moduleProperty = 1;
    my.moduleMethod = function () {
        // ...
    };

    return my;
}());
```